# How to check if my Android Phone USB C connector has DP Alt Mode capability?

Tags: hdmi, usb-c

My Android Phone has a USB C adapter, how do I know that it has [DP ALT mode](https://www.displayport.org/displayport-over-usb-c/) capability before I buy a USB C to HDMI extension cable?

This question is similar for [that inquires the same for laptops](https://superuser.com/questions/1242772/how-to-check-if-my-computer-has-a-usb-c-that-can-be-used-for-display-port).

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to test if USB-C supports DP-alternate or not without trying it. So the only alternative is tell us your phone manufacturer and model name and hope that somebody has already tried it with your phone model or search common Android forums for topics on USB DP-alternate for your model.